# Creating a list of fields in django

Tags: python, django

I need to create a model which contains a list. This is how far i got till now

```
    class Language(models.Model):
      name = models.TextField()
      def __str__(self):
         return self.name
      def __unicode(self):
         return self.name

    class Education(models.Model):
      mother_language = models.TextField()
      foreign_languages = models.ForeignKey(Language)
      def __str__(self):
         return self.mother_language # + ' ' + list_of_self.foreign_languages
      def __unicode__(self):
         return self.mother_language # + ' ' + list_of_self.foreign_languages
```

What I want is to write something like foreign_languages=['English', 'German'] and i want to be able to print it like above.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the field type from `ForeignKey` to `ManyToMany` and then try something like:

```
', '.join(unicode(x) for x in self.foreign_languages.all())
```

Comment: Thanks man, i didn't manage to do it earlier, this helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

For that I am afraid you will need to override **setaddr**

setattr">http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**setattr**

You need to check on the property being set, basically do nothing in all the cases except for "language", where you will have to iterate over the list, add the missing languages in the model, and then add them to the class.